# Commit using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms-services

I 'm looking for a solution to submit an item using JavaScript for a button already placed on the form like this.....

```
$( "#ctl00_m_g_a8a7fbc3_43a2_4418_83f6_b76759ed345a_FormControl0_V1_I1_B4").click(function() {
    //Commit here!!
});
```

I've seen solutions where JavaScript will create the button, I'm just not sure how to incorporate the script into this example or if it will work. Below is the solution I've been finding on various blogs/sites etc. I've tried various configurations with no success...Thanks.

```
<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Save Changes" 
 id="Submit1" style="width:140px" 
 onclick="javascript: {
    ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')};
    window.alert('Item updated.');
    window.close();"/>
```

Comment: Do you want to update the item? If yes, you can look into executing a `MERGE` request with REST api.

Comment: Add and update...

Comment: If you're in 2013, you can use REST api to do this. Have a read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api.aspx